# SQL scalar function update

Tags: sql, scalar

i have one scalar function where there are exceptions set, i need to add some more to the scalar function using a query , is it similar to insert on a table to a add in the scalar function ,

my idea is to update it from the new interface is there a way

Comment: No it's similar to editing a Stored Procedure, ALTER is your friend here.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.